# flutter build apk fails - Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, flutter-build

here is the complete output :

I tried switching to stable channel and ran these commands already.

1. flutter channel stable
2. flutter upgrade
3. flutter run

Even on stable channel the error doesn't go !

```
    C:\Users\Rudr\Documents\GitHub\Flutter-Facial-Attendance-App\facatte>flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on SM M315F in debug mode...
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > project :firebase_core
         project :app > project :firebase_ml_vision
         project :app > project :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle
         project :app > project :google_maps_flutter
         project :app > project :image_picker
         project :app > project :path_provider
         project :app > project :geocoder
         project :app > project :cloud_firestore
         project :app > project :firebase_analytics
         project :app > project :firebase_auth
         project :app > project :geolocator
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4/x86_debug-1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4/x86_debug-1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        69.8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: How to fix this issue bro?

Comment: actually the server was under maintenance so it was not downloading. Sometime later the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

The download is under maintenance.
subscribe to https://status.bintray.com/ to get the latest updates.