# flutter doctor --android-licenses Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

Tags: java, flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
D:\>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1256], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.   

 D:\>flutter doctor --android-licenses
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
            at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
            at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
            at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
            at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
            at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
            ... 5 more
```

running on latest stable version Java 8(Update 271) and JDK 15.0.1.

running on Windows 10 Home.

Also flutter version is :

Flutter 1.22.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7891006299 (13 days ago) • 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
Engine • revision ae90085a84
Tools • Dart 2.10.4

Comment: It was working fine on jdk 14 yesterday but i was facing issues building the apk. refer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65411479/flutter-build-apk-fails-could-not-determine-the-dependencies-of-task-apppro

So i thght i would reinstall everything and maybe it would work and now its throwing this error ! It was working fine earlier

Comment: Check whether android command line tools are installed or not. You can follow this github wiki and solve the issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57017

Comment: Okay so here's how I solved it . 1) Install Android Studio 2) Go to SDK Manager > SDK Platforms > download SDK for Android 11(R) and Android 10(Q)  3) go to SDK tools tab and download Android SDK Command line tools . And the errors were gone ! I guess the command line tools were missing which i forgot to reinstall that caused this issue . Thanks alot

Comment: Happy to know that it worked. Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score -1):

OK!

1. I see no IDE (Android Studio / VS Code)
2. you need to download one of the Android SDK to continue
3. No Connected devices (which also means, you didn't enable the web also)
4. After resolving these you should go for android licenses.

Comment: 1) Not necessary 2) You can see the SDK version in error log (so it's already there) 3) Not necessary (Flutter web is still in beta and he is using stable channel)

Comment: Thanks, @Midhun, I didn't know about those :)

Comment: No worries. Happy Coding!